# Can Python generate list of all possible part numbers with given criteria?

Tags: python, database, combinatorics

I am new to Python. As in really new, just venturing if I can use this language in my work.

Can Python generate all the possible part numbers from this list?

Condition:

1. Characters are ordered

It can have **ERJ***3R*BD1002V, but not *3R***ERJ**BD1002V.

Thank you so much.

[PartNumbers](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vq0wd.jpg)

Comment: Well, yes, you can certainly write a Python script to do this, but 1) you didn't give nearly enough information for the problem to make sense yet, and 2) it sounds like you're asking for someone to do the work for you. Here, we prefer that you give the problem a shot yourself, and ask for help when you get stuck, rather than just state what you need and hope someone does it all.

Comment: *"Can Python generate all the possible part numbers from this list?"* What list?

Comment: maybe take a look at the [`itertools`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html) library (built-in)

Comment: if these are ISBN numbers or something similar they likely have some additional restrictions, e.g. a checksum, and/or a hierarchical structure so you may want to consider using any of these sorts of criteria-if they apply-to filter out invalid/impossible values.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: Aww sorry it didn't saved the picture. Question was edited to show link of picture.

Comment: This is not hard at all, but remember that you'll need a list of the valid resistance values.  There aren't 10,000 valid resistor values.

Comment: @joanis I'm sorry it sounded like that to you. Like what I said, I am only new -really new- to Python so I'm just trying to know if it is worth it to learn, and if it is, I will do the code myself. I didn't ask for anyone to do the code itself, why would I do that. I only asked if it can be done.

Comment: OK, the question makes a lot more sense with the picture! And thanks for clarifying your intent. Yes, Python is definitely worth learning, although this problem can fairly easily be solved in just about any programming language.

Comment: @joanis yeah, sorry about that. Thought I included the picture. I'm just venturing on to the programming stuff right now, as my current work team is more on MS Excel and MS Access :/ Also I'm sorry I sounded a bit harsh on my reply. And well, I'm into SQL right now, so I thought that might also work. Thanks bro/sis.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes it can, except for the resistance values part (8,9,10,11) since those can be a whole list of values and the link you provided doesn't list them.

Here is a simple code to do it. It will put `RRRR` into the resistance value part. If you have a list of resistance values, just add them to list `R` and it will use those to create the combinations:

```
B = ['1R','2R','3R','6R']
C = ['H','B','K', 'E']
R = ['RRRR']
V = {'1R': 'C', '2R': 'x', '3R': 'V', '6R': 'V'}

for bi in B:
    for ci in C:
        for ri in R:
            print ('ERJ '+ bi + ' ' + ci + ' D ' + ri + ' ' + V[bi])
```

I put in extra spaces between sections for clarity but you can remove them if you like

Comment: Thanks a lot! I'm beginning to see why Python is a must for data science. Thanks again!

Comment: You're welcome. If it does what you need, please consider accepting the answer.